# joining dataframes by closest time and another key in r

Tags: r

I want to merge/join two data frames by nearest timestamp and another key.

I have created some dummy data:

```
tm<-c('22/03/2012 11:50',   '22/03/2012 14:40', '10/01/2012 3:21',   
'10/01/2012 6:48',  '10/01/2012 7:30')
vgid<-c('a',    'a',    'a',    'b',    'b')
count<- c(34,   56, 767,    88, 990)

d1<-data.frame(tm, vgid, count)

tm<-c('22/03/2012 11:51',   '22/03/2012 14:41', '10/01/2012 3:21',   
'10/01/2012 6:41',  '10/01/2012 7:31')
vgid<-c('b',    'b',    'a',    'b',    'b')
dcount<-c(35,   678,    88, 55, 33)

d2<-data.frame(tm, vgid, dcount)
```

format the time

```
d1$tm<-dmy_hm(d1$tm)
d2$tm<-dmy_hm(d2$tm)
```

and ran the following code

```
d   <- function(x,y) abs(x-y) # define the distance function
idx <- sapply(d1$tm, function(x) which.min( d(x,d2$tm) )) # find matches

d12tb<-cbind(d1,d2[idx,-1,drop=FALSE])

d12tb
```

which gives

```
 tm              vgid count  vgid   dcount
2012-03-22 11:50:00 a   34  b   35
2012-03-22 14:40:00 a   56  b   678
2012-01-10 03:21:00 a   767 a   88
2012-01-10 06:48:00 b   88  b   55
2012-01-10 07:30:00 b   990 b   33
```

I would like the results to look like:

```
tm                vgid  count   xtm         xvgid   dcount
22/03/2012 11:50    a   34    na               na       na
na                 na   na  22/03/2012 11:51   b        35
22/03/2012 14:40    a   56    na                na       na
na                 na   na   22/03/2012 14:41  b        678
10/01/2012 3:21    a    767 10/01/2012 3:21    a       88
10/01/2012 6:48    b    88   10/01/2012 6:41   b       55
10/01/2012 7:30    b    990 10/01/2012 7:31    b       33
```

or better still

```
22/03/2012 11:50    a   34  na                na    na
22/03/2012 11:51    b   na  22/03/2012 11:51    b   35
22/03/2012 14:40    a   56  na                na    na
22/03/2012 14:41    b   na  22/03/2012 14:41    b   678
10/01/2012 3:21     a   767 10/01/2012 3:21      a  88
10/01/2012 6:48     b   88  10/01/2012 6:41      b  55
10/01/2012 7:30     b   990 10/01/2012 7:31      b  33
```

Obviously I need to include the 'vgid' key as well but have not been able to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: I don't get the logic of your combination/overlap. Why is `10/01/2012 6:48` and `10/01/2012 6:41` the same row, while `22/03/2012 14:40` and  `22/03/2012 14:41` are separated?

Comment: due to ~6.40 being the same voyage (b) and 14.40 and 14.41 different voyages (a & b)

Comment: Maybe you could use `data.table`'s [rolling joins](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/r-data-table-rolling-joins/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got close to required join with:

```
d1$tmn<-as.numeric(d1$tm)
d2$tmn<-as.numeric(d2$tm)

d12<-fuzzy_join(
  d1, d2,
  by = c(
     "tmn"="tmn",
    "vgid" = "vgid"
  ),
  match_fun = list(`==`, `==`)
  )
d12


tm.x              vgid.x count tmn.x     tm.y             vgid.y dcount tmn.y
2012-01-10 03:21:00 a   767 1326165660  2012-01-10 03:21:00 a   88  1326165660
```

It doesn't give exactly what I was after in my example (see expected results) but as my real data had start and end times I was able to use < and > the time to create the join keys. If any one can add to this so as I can attain my expected results?